# Trim from a space or tab onward or backwards in Java

Tags: java, trim

I know how to trim things in Java but how does one trim from a space or tab to the left or to the right? I have a program that searches for some 4 character prefixes let’s say this prefix is `XYBC` then it has X amount of characters to it like `XYBC4975723434` but the line that my code takes looks like this:

`Viuhaskfdksjfkds  XYBC4975723434 fkdsjkfjaksjfklsdakldjsen`

But then I would like it to trim it to this: `XYBC4975723434`
Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you want to `split()` your input string on whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a trim, but a regular expression find, using the following regex:

```
\bXYBC.*?\b
```

That expression used word boundaries, which may not be what you want.

For whitespace, use:

```
(?<=^|\s)XYBC\S*
```

*Test*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("Viuhaskfdksjfkds  XYBC4975723434 fkdsjkfjaksjfklsdakldjsen");
    test("XYBC4975723434");
    test("Viuhaskfdksjfkds  xXYBC4975723434 fkdsjkfjaksjfklsdakldjsen");
    test("abc XYBC49-75(723)4$34 xyz");
}
private static void test(String text) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\bXYBC.*?\\b").matcher(text);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not found: " + text);
    }
}
```

*Output (word boundary)*

```
XYBC4975723434
XYBC4975723434
Not found: Viuhaskfdksjfkds  xXYBC4975723434 fkdsjkfjaksjfklsdakldjsen
XYBC49
```

*Output (whitespace)*

```
XYBC4975723434
XYBC4975723434
Not found: Viuhaskfdksjfkds  xXYBC4975723434 fkdsjkfjaksjfklsdakldjsen
XYBC49-75(723)4$34
```

Answer (score 2):

> I have a prog that searches for some 4 character prefixes let’s say this prefix is XYBC then it has X amount of characters to it

If you want your program to grab a substring with specific starting letters and grab a specific number of letters, you may do this (apart from using regular expression):

```
public static String grabText(String str, String find, int n){
    int idx = str.indexOf(find);    
    if(idx == -1)
        return "";
    else{
       String sub = str.substring(idx, Math.min(n, str.length() - idx)+ idx);
        return sub; 
    }
}
```

**TEST:**

```
String str = "Viuhaskfdksjfkds  XYBC4975723434 fkdsjkfjaksjfklsdakldjsen";
System.out.println(grabText(str, "XYBC", 14));
System.out.println(grabText(str, "XYBC", 5));           
System.out.println(grabText(str, "XYBC", 100)); 
System.out.println(grabText(str, "XYBC", 9999));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
XYBC4975723434
XYBC4
XYBC4975723434 fkdsjkfjaksjfklsdakldjsen
XYBC4975723434 fkdsjkfjaksjfklsdakldjsen
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to achieve this. For example, by using the regular expression `XYBC\d+`, you can match or find any sequence of numbers which are prefixed with `XYBC`. In code, that would look like this:

```java
String input = "Viuhaskfdksjfkds  XYBC4975723434 fkdsjkfjaksjfklsdakldjsen";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("XYBC\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

if (!matcher.find()) throw new RuntimeException("failed to find any numbers prefixed with XYBC!");

System.out.println(matcher.group()); // prints "XYBC4975723434"
```

Also check out the details of the given regular expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/hH3zL1/1).